# How to access SVN file directly from Python

Tags: python, pysvn

I am trying to automate file search using python and I want to do it directly on the SVN repository. I used the pysvn module but certain attributes like checkout , info2 etc do not work as it says these attributes are not related to the pysvn.Client.

Can anyone guide me through these issues.
Thanks in advance.

```
client = pysvn.Client()
client.checkout()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAybI.png)

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**